# Any OpenCV 3 with Kinetic?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, opencv3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the recommended platforms found here:

http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html

Can any OpenCV 3 be installed with Kinetic? My project leans more toward OpenCV than ROS so I'd like to get OpenCV 3.4.6 (or any 3.4 really) if possible - I read somewhere the default with Kinetic was 3.1 or 3.2.

Also there is no compatibility with OpenCV 4.1 for any ROS distribution, correct?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328397/any-opencv-3-with-kinetic?/) by [cjk11091](https://answers.ros.org/users/44049/cjk11091/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-07-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that Kinetic comes with OpenCV 3.2 or 3.3 by default.

You can use newer versions of OpenCV with ROS, but you will have to modify and compile any other ROS packages which use OpenCV to use the same version you compiled.

So far this is no compatibility for OpenCV 4.1 even for Melodic or Dashing. I took a brief stab at building the package for OpenCV 4.1, but it wasn't as simple as upgrading between OpenCV 3 versions. You may be able to build OpenCV from scratch on each system, and then modify/recompile the other ROS packages that depend on OpenCV.

---

Originally posted by [daniel_dsouza](https://answers.ros.org/users/22498/daniel_dsouza/) with karma: 258 on 2019-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0